# Call chromium within a Python script in crontab

Tags: python, cron, chromium

I'm doing a digital signage project for a marketing agency that I work for. I have a Python Script that when called manually in Shell does everything, log and then opens Chromium.

But when It starts via crontab it does everything, log, but don't open the Chromium, and does not present any error.

I'm using `subprocess.Popen` command to open Chromium via Shell.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can't run GUI programs from crontab. It doesn't have the environment set up to run in the GUI.

Comment: Even if i open then from python?

Comment: Yes. Use another method that's run from a GUI program. Start a program from the GUI autostart that runs something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/16786600/3491475

Comment: What operating system you are using? How often do you want to execute the script with crontab? Every minute? What is the script? Can you paste it into the question? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a call up in /etc/rc.local for a kiosk.sh script. Then add the call for Chrome and the URL (or set the homepage to the URL and just call Chrome) with -kiosk if full screen is required. I'll add how I have it set up as an answer when I can access a work Pi. Tip: Install xautomation to be able to send key presses (like F11, enter or login details). Hiding the curser and stopping screensaver are advised too.